# How to restrict scanner object to accept anything after enter key is pressed

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int tosend = sc.nextInt();
```

1. I want that user should be able to only enter any one number after
   that scanner object should be stopped accepting anything after the enter key is pressed but I don't want to close this object because I need it later.

I am developing bingo card game. In that all player will get chance one by one.
Every player have to enter only one number at a time.
consider if a player P1 got his chance and he enters two numbers(example num1 and num2) at the same time seperated by enter key is pressed.whenever he will  get the next chance the second number which is num2 will be considered as his played number,server skips his chance and considers this num2 is played number but this was the number of his previous chance.I want to skip scanner object to store the second number to be stored in its buffer.

Comment: Scanner just reads from `System.in` - you have very little control of the terminal emulator to control allowed input. The best you can do is read the input and error if it’s invalid.

Comment: You can ideally close the Scanner object to stop users from providing more input. However, you don't want to do that. So, you will have to have a validator in the code. The validator can parse the user input, detect that there are more than 1 inputs given and then decide to take just the 1st element.